# structr.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install

Tags: installation, structr

try to install the structr version 4.2.0 in ubuntu but terminal shows "structr.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install." after running the command "sudo service structr start it shows nothing"

structr-4.2.0 downloaded on system and try to install the structr using command line (

```
sudo dpkg -i structr-4.2.0.deb)
```

Comment: `sudo service structr start` only starts structr in the background.

What does `sudo service structr status` return?

You should also see activity in `/var/log/structr.log`.

With the default config, structr should start a web server on `localhost:8082` (if nothing is running there already).

Comment: sudo service structr status  is   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-11-16 12:58:58